# Event triggered animations of elements of ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xaml, storyboard, observablecollection, eventhandler

**Background**

I'm writing a Windows Store app in C# / XAML that incorporates multiple ObservableCollections. The elements in these collections subscribe to a number of Events to start a variety of Storyboard animations defined in XAML.
This all works fine so long as I manually Add the elements to panels defined in XAML: the elements get displayed and animate as intended e.g. when tapped.

**What I’m trying to do**

But this misses the point about some of the great powers of the ObservableCollection: when the collection changes (e.g. elements added or removed) I still have to manually reflect this in the corresponding panel.
As I understand it, the solution is to connect the ObservableCollections to the panels using Data Binding so that these panels get updated dynamically whenever a collection changes. I think I also understand that doing this with a StackPanel requires an ItemsControl (because StackPanel doesn’t have ItemSource…?)

**Where I get stuck**

Where I get stuck is with the animations: whatever I try, data binding the panels with the collections somehow causes a ‘*Cannot resolve TargetName*’ error that wasn’t a problem before.

What is **a correct way to change** my example code below so that MyStackPanel is connected to the MyBuilding ObservableCollection using Data Binding? Any help very much appreciated.

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="TappedAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-15"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="15"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" Grid.Column="0"/>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code behind**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Button[] MyBrick = new Button[4];
            ObservableCollection<Button> MyBuilding = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                MyBrick[i] = new Button();
                MyBrick[i].Content = "My Button  " + (i+1).ToString();
                MyBrick[i].Name = "MyButton" + (i + 1).ToString();
                MyBrick[i].ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
                MyBrick[i].RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                MyBrick[i].RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
                MyBrick[i].Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(brick_Tapped);
                MyBuilding.Add(MyBrick[i]);
                MyStackPanel.Children.Add(MyBrick[i]);
            }

            MyBuilding.Remove(MyBrick[2]); // how to get this dynamically reflected in MyStackPanel?
        }

        private void brick_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TappedAnimation.Stop();
            TappedAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, (sender as Button).Name);
            TappedAnimation.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```